# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?' when doing writeStorage

Tags: flutter, dart, storage

I am facing a little weird error for me

`Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'`

when

`await storage.writeData('id', jsonDecode(request2.body)['data']['id']);`

I printed that parameter it gives me `199` but I have no idea where is problem here?
I can't save int as a value for map? It makes no sense. Btw. I have identical line in other part of code and there is working without any errors so I am clueless at this point

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [code Snippet](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c0993d2b1941bf2750618268c10d9e1a) what exactly do you need if i am not wrong it will help you.